# Listview only getting 1st items

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a ListView and it retrieves 3 items within it, then I have this code when Data is retrieved and put into the ListView

```
protected void car_listview_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var lbl = car_listview.Items[0].FindControl("lbl1") as Label;
        lbl.Text = "Car";
}
```

However the problem I am getting is that it only changes the first item's lbl and not the 2nd nor the 3rd.

I can't use Eval as I am planning to do IF statements to show different values in the lbl.Text property so is their a way to fix my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView.DataBound` event fires when the entire control has finished binding data to the control. So it only fires once per `ListView`. If you want to change the `Label` on each item, iterate through the `ListView.Items` collection and change the values there, or use `ListView.ItemDataBound` event which fires per each data item. You can access the inserted item through the arguments in the event handler.

--Edit--

The code for finding the label within the handler, try something like this:

```
protected void car_listview_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Label _label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl");
        if (_label != null)
        {
            //code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use ItemDataBound, so if I had a label called lbl in the ItemTemplate how would I access it through the arguments?